# filebeat-logstash with clickhouse for docker container logs are not pushing

Tags: docker, logstash, clickhouse, filebeat

Below is my configs for FileBeat and Logstash, i just followed [this](https://github.com/un-knower/logstash-to-clickhouse) code. but i'm trying to push the docker container logs to ClickHouse.

Running the filebeat with below docker cmd. I think the Clickhouse log table and logstash log is not matching.

```
docker run --rm -it --name=filebeat --user=root \
--volume="/var/log/:/var/log/" \
--volume="/var/lib/docker/containers/:/var/lib/docker/containers/" \
--volume="$(pwd)/filebeat.docker.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml" \
docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:5.6.3 filebeat -e -strict.perms=false
```

> filebeat.yml

```
filebeat.prospectors:
  - input_type: log
    paths:
      - /var/log/*.log
      - /var/lib/docker/containers/*.log   
    exclude_files: ['.gz$']
output.logstash:
  hosts: ['localhost:5044']
```

> logstash.conf

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
      grok {
        match => [ "message" , "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}+%{GREEDYDATA:extra_fields}"]
      }

      mutate {
        convert => ["response", "integer"]
        convert => ["bytes", "integer"]
        convert => ["responsetime", "float"]
        remove_field => ["@version", "host", "message", "beat", "offset", "type", "tags", "input_type", "source"]
      }

      date {
        match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
        remove_field => [ "timestamp", "@timestamp" ]
        target => [ "logdatetime" ]
      }

      ruby {
        code => "tstamp = event.get('logdatetime').to_i
                 event.set('logdatetime', Time.at(tstamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
                 event.set('logdate', Time.at(tstamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))"
      }

      useragent {
        source => "agent"
      }

     prune {
          interpolate => true
          whitelist_names => ["^logdate$" ,"^logdatetime$" ,"^request$" ,"^agent$" ,"^os$" ,"^minor$" ,"^auth$" ,"^ident$" ,"^verb$" ,"^patch$" ,"^referrer$" ,"^major$" ,"^build$" ,"^response$","^bytes$","^clientip$" ,"^name$" ,"^os_name$" ,"^httpversion$" ,"^device$" ]
        }
}
output {
    clickhouse {
      http_hosts => ["http://localhost:8123"]
      table => "nginx_access"
      request_tolerance => 1
      flush_size => 1000
      pool_max => 1000
    }
}
```

> filebeat logs

```
2023/02/09 09:45:22.247315 spooler.go:63: INFO Starting spooler: spool_size: 2048; idle_timeout: 5s
2023/02/09 09:45:22.247331 prospector.go:124: INFO Starting prospector of type: log; id: 7589403446011535719 
2023/02/09 09:45:22.247356 crawler.go:58: INFO Loading and starting Prospectors completed. Enabled prospectors: 1
2023/02/09 09:45:22.247929 log.go:91: INFO Harvester started for file: /var/log/falcond.log
2023/02/09 09:45:22.247982 log.go:91: INFO Harvester started for file: /var/log/yum.log
2023/02/09 09:45:22.248088 log.go:91: INFO Harvester started for file: /var/log/falconctl.log
2023/02/09 09:45:22.248622 log.go:91: INFO Harvester started for file: /var/log/boot.log
2023/02/09 09:45:22.248665 log.go:91: INFO Harvester started for file: /var/log/falcon-sensor.log
2023/02/09 09:45:52.239459 metrics.go:39: INFO Non-zero metrics in the last 30s: filebeat.harvester.open_files=5 filebeat.harvester.running=5 filebeat.harvester.started=5 libbeat.logstash.call_count.PublishEvents=1 libbeat.logstash.publish.read_bytes=24 libbeat.logstash.publish.write_bytes=3764 libbeat.logstash.published_and_acked_events=77 libbeat.publisher.published_events=77 publish.events=82 registrar.states.current=5 registrar.states.update=82 registrar.writes=2
2023/02/09 09:46:22.239403 metrics.go:34: INFO No non-zero metrics in the last 30s
2023/02/09 09:46:52.239518 metrics.go:34: INFO No non-zero metrics in the last 30s
2023/02/09 09:47:22.239436 metrics.go:34: INFO No non-zero metrics in the last 30s
```

Comment: > No non-zero metrics in the last 30s

Are you sure you have new data in /var/log/*.log files?

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested why you have chosen Logstash and not something Fluentbit / Vector for log tailing...both of those have native ClickHouse integrations.

https://clickhouse.com/blog/storing-log-data-in-clickhouse-fluent-bit-vector-open-telemetry

Comment: i'm exploring different agents for collecting logs and send it to ClickHouse.